# What is the difference between using System.Drawing.Size and $button.Top & $button.Left in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface, system.drawing

I have been designing a GUI in Powershell (*never thought I'd use that sentence*) and, while looking at different sources online, there are different methods for positioning Control Items withing a form.

When I first starting familiarizing myself with the basic framework on how to build a simple form, it shows this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Top = 30
$button.Left = 30
$form.Controls.Add($button)
```

However, looking around, I have seen most places use this method:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,30)
$form.Controls.Add($button)
```

It appears to accomplish the exact same thing.

Different ways to do the same thing is what makes programming interesting (to me, anyway). What I would like to know is if there is a reason why the latter is more commonly demonstrated and if there is a reason why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. At the end it is exactly the same. All three properties are derived from system.windows.forms.control.

---

The documentation from Microsoft says:

> [Control.Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.left(v=vs.110).aspx): Gets or sets the distance, in pixels, between the left edge of the control and the left edge of its container's client area [...]
>   The Left property value is equivalent to the Point.X property of the Location property value of the control.
>
> [Control.Top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.top(v=vs.110).aspx): Gets or sets the distance, in pixels, between the top edge of the control and the top edge of its container's client area. [...] The Top property value is equivalent to the Point.Y property of the Location property value of the control.

---

It's up to you what you'd like to use in a specific scenario. The only real difference I see, is that for setting the Location you need a new object (value type). For just setting top or left you only need an [int].

Comment: Awesome! It looked like System.Drawing.Size($control.Left, $control.Top) was likely but Windows has a tendency to keep redundant tools and methodologies for ease of use.